# Varnish using the wrong outgoing IP?

Tags: linux, web-server, http, web-hosting, varnish

I have the following Varnish configuration:

```
backend default {
.host = "127.0.0.1";
.port = "8080";
}
acl purge {
"127.0.0.1";
}
sub vcl_recv {
#cloudflare
  remove req.http.X-Forwarded-For;
  if (req.http.cf-connecting-ip) {
    set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = req.http.cf-connecting-ip;
  } else {
    set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;
  }
# Remove has_js and CloudFlare/Google Analytics __* cookies.
  set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "(^|;\s*)(_[_a-z]+|has_js)=[^;]*", "");
  # Remove a ";" prefix, if present.
  set req.http.Cookie = regsub(req.http.Cookie, "^;\s*", "");
# Let's make sure we aren't compressing already compressed formats.
if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
if (req.url ~ "\.(jpg|png|gif|gz|tgz|bz2|mp3|mp4|m4v)(\?.*|)$") {
remove req.http.Accept-Encoding;
} elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "gzip") {
set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "gzip";
} elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "deflate") {
set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "deflate";
} else {
remove req.http.Accept-Encoding;
}
}
if (req.request == "PURGE") {
if (!client.ip ~ purge) {
error 405 "Not allowed.";
}
return(lookup);
}
if (req.url ~ "^/$") {
unset req.http.cookie;
}
}
sub vcl_hit {
if (req.request == "PURGE") {
set obj.ttl = 0s;
error 200 "Purged.";
}
}
sub vcl_miss {
if (req.request == "PURGE") {
error 404 "Not in cache.";
}
if (!(req.url ~ "wp-(login|admin)")) {
unset req.http.cookie;
}
if (req.url ~ "^/[^?]+.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif|ico|js|css|txt|gz|zip|lzma|bz2|tgz|tbz|html|htm)(\?.|)$") {
unset req.http.cookie;
set req.url = regsub(req.url, "\?.$", "");
}
if (req.url ~ "^/$") {
unset req.http.cookie;
}
}
sub vcl_fetch {
if (req.url ~ "^/$") {
unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
}
if (!(req.url ~ "wp-(login|admin)")) {
unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
}
}
sub vcl_pipe {
        set bereq.http.connection = "close";
        if (req.http.X-Forwarded-For) {
                set bereq.http.X-Forwarded-For = req.http.X-Forwarded-For;
        } else {
                set bereq.http.X-Forwarded-For = regsub(client.ip, ":.*", "");
          }
    }
    sub vcl_pass {
        set bereq.http.connection = "close";
        if (req.http.X-Forwarded-For) {
                set bereq.http.X-Forwarded-For = req.http.X-Forwarded-For;
        } else {
          set bereq.http.X-Forwarded-For = regsub(client.ip, ":.*", "");
          }
    }
```

When my web app connects to the licence server I get "invalid licence key". if I take varnish down everything works.  What could be going wrong?

Comment: The license server doesn't permit connections to go through a proxy, likely because this is viewed as a means of cheating the licensing. Check the logs on the license server.

Comment: Is there a way to tunnel or skip the /admin side or the web app from using the proxy when going out or something? I won't have access to lic server as this is not my made web app.

Comment: What is the purpose of the varnish server?

Comment: Cache content and decrease page load time.

Comment: What do you mean by "web app connects to the license server"?  If the connection is initiated from the web application servers, the Varnish server isn't involved at all..

Comment: Well I don't know. I just know the lic protocol is initiated when I view the web app. It's WHMCS and coded in PHP.

Comment: Could the sub vlc_pass or another rule set be trying to pass the wrong IP to the lic server?